# How to use leaflet slider along with markercluster in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, openstreetmap

i am making a map that uses a slider to show or hide markers, and i want to add clustering functionality, each one alone works perfectly, but i want the slider to show the markers, and in case of markers very close to use a cluster. the problem is that both, the individual and the marker clusters are showing, i want the shown markers to cluster not clusters being there all the time

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var sliderControl = null;
                    //creating layers
                    var cities = new L.LayerGroup();
                    var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenstreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                    'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
                    mbUrl = 'https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
                    var grayscale = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {id: 'remote-sensing.n8k508ak', attribution: mbAttr, accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmVtb3RlLXNlbnNpbmciLCJhIjoiYWNiYzg0ZWU2Mjk3ZTU5NjE4MmQyZWEzZTY2ZWNlYjIifQ.U7mp4MXdcjaIwW_syAqriQ'})
                    , streets = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {id: 'remote-sensing.84f6c85a', attribution: mbAttr, accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmVtb3RlLXNlbnNpbmciLCJhIjoiYWNiYzg0ZWU2Mjk3ZTU5NjE4MmQyZWEzZTY2ZWNlYjIifQ.U7mp4MXdcjaIwW_syAqriQ'});
                    //create and add the layers to the map
                    var map = L.map('map', {
                    center: [33.9, 35.877],
                            zoom: 10,
                            layers: [ streets, cities]
                    });
     
  
                    //get length of the entries array
                    var len = "{{events|length}}";
                    var date = 1;
                    var time = 2;
                    var lat = 4;
                    var lon = 5;
                    //get events from database
                    var stri = "{% for event in events %} {{event.timestamp|date:"Y-m-d H"}}  {{event.lat}} {{event.lon}} <br>  {% endfor %}";
                    var entry =  stri.split(" ");
                    //create the clustermarker object
                    var markers = new L.markerClusterGroup();
                    //create markers and add to cluster
     var mymark;
                    for (var t = 0; t < len; t++) {
     mymark = new L.marker([entry[lat], entry[lon]], {time: "\"" + entry[date] + entry[time] + "+01\""});
                    mymark.bindPopup("<b>Accident</b><br>this is marker number " + (t + 1) + " with coordinates :[" + entry[lat] + "," + entry[lon] + "]").openPopup();
                    markers.addLayer(mymark);
                    date += 8;
                    time += 8;
                    lat += 8;
                    lon += 8;
            }
 mymark = new L.marker([33.8,35.5]);
 markers.addLayer(mymark);                                       
 mymark = new L.marker([33.8,35.5]);
 markers.addLayer(mymark);  
 mymark = new L.marker([33.8,35.5]);
 markers.addLayer(mymark);  
 mymark = new L.marker([33.8,35.5]);
 markers.addLayer(mymark);  
 mymark = new L.marker([33.8,35.5]);
 markers.addLayer(mymark);  
 mymark = new L.marker([33.8,35.5]);
 markers.addLayer(mymark);  
 mymark = new L.marker([33.8,35.5]);
 markers.addLayer(mymark);  
 mymark = new L.marker([33.8,35.5]);
 markers.addLayer(mymark);  
 mymark = new L.marker([33.8,35.5]);
 markers.addLayer(mymark);   
            //add cluster to map
          // map.addLayer(markers);
                    //baseLayers for the map
                    var baseLayers = {
                    "Grayscale": grayscale,
                            "streets": streets
                    };
     layerGroup = L.layerGroup(markers);
 // $.getJSON("data.geojson", function(data) {

    //  var testlayer = L.geoJson(data);
      var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({  position: "topright",   layer: markers,  range: false , follow: 3});
            // ({position: "topright", layer: testlayer, follow: 3});
map.addControl(sliderControl);
sliderControl.startSlider();//});
        </script>
```

sorry for some comments, some are just actual code made as comments for debuggung

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit March 2016:**

You can now simply use the plugin [Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport) to achieve this, without having to change Leaflet Slider plugin code.

See the demo [LayerSupport with LeafletSlider plugin](http://ghybs.github.io/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport/examples/mcgLayerSupport-leafletslider.html).

In your case, you would do:

```js
var markers = L.layerGroup();

// Add all your markers into `markers` Layer Group.

// Check into MCG Layer Support!
// Add to map first before checking in.
L.markerClusterGroup.layerSupport().addTo(map).checkIn(markers);

var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
  position: "topright",
  layer: markers,
  range: false,
  follow: 3
});

map.addControl(sliderControl);
sliderControl.startSlider();
```

> Disclosure: I am the author of that plugin.

---

**Original answer:**

Refrain from adding (removing) individual markers directly to (from) the map, when they are handled by a MarkerClusterGroup which is on the map at the same time.

MCG expects to be the only group managing the markers, and if you want to show / hide some of the markers, you have to use `markers.addLayer(myMarker);` (or `removeLayer`), where `markers` is your MCG.

The Leaflet Time-Slider (sliderControl) plugin is therefore incompatible as-is with MCG: it directly adds (removes) markers to (from) the map. It does not know anything about your MCG.

Nevertheless, you should be able to make it compatible with MCG by replacing any `map.addLayer` by `markers.addLayer` (same for `removeLayer`) in the plugin code. Do not forget to add your MCG to the map.

Comment: thanks, already did it but would have been helpful if you found my question earlier, thanks again

Comment: Thank you for having still accepted this answer. I am glad you have been able to make it work! Hopefully this can still help other people who may face a similar issue in the future.