# Leaflet Slider and Marker Cluster - time not sorted

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markerclusterer, jquery-ui-slider

I use leaflet markercluster along with the ui slider (modified so it can handle a markercluster group as a entry layer, see [How to use leaflet slider along with markercluster in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886588/how-to-use-leaflet-slider-along-with-markercluster-in-javascript)).

I managed to make it work except "time" is not sorted in my slider. I don't know what rule SliderControl.js follows to sort the markers but it seems random to me. My data variable (Data_GL) is well time sorted and I specified "timeStrLength: 10" in SliderControl.js.

Here's my code :

```
var sliderControl = null;

var map = L.map('map').setView([23, 2], 3);
map.options.maxZoom=13;

var osmUrl='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var osmAttrib='Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors';
L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {attribution: osmAttrib, id: 'mapbox.streets'}).addTo(map);

var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
markers.addTo(map);

//Filling layer
var mapdata=Data_GL;

for (var i = 0; i < mapdata.length; i++) {
  var marker = L.marker([mapdata[i].latitude,mapdata[i].longitude],{title: mapdata[i].Platform,icon: cssic0,time: mapdata[i].time});
  marker.bindPopup(mapdata[i].Platform + "<br><b>Type </b>: " + mapdata[i].mtype + "<br><b>Last Update </b>: " + mapdata[i].time);
  console.log(marker.time);
  marker.addTo(markers);};

//Slider
var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({layer:markers , range:true});
map.addControl(sliderControl);

sliderControl.startSlider();
```

Data_GL looks like that :

```
var Data_GL = [
{"latitude":37.783380,"longitude":15.956680,"mtype":"GL","Platform":"61283","time":"2005-02-21"}, 
{"latitude":37.864970,"longitude":15.826730,"mtype":"GL","Platform":"61282","time":"2005-02-25"}, 
{"latitude":47.639170,"longitude":-8.469670,"mtype":"GL","Platform":"62595","time":"2006-03-12"}, 
{"latitude":59.562670,"longitude":-39.745000,"mtype":"GL","Platform":"64556","time":"2006-08-24"},
...
```

I tried this solution (http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/ngeLm8c0/4/) but I don't really know how to apply it to a markercluster group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately [LeafletSlider](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider) plugin does not sort layers automatically, even though it does read and show a timestamp.

That is why in the post related to the JSFiddle you mention, the author proposes to `sort` the input GeoJSON features.

(related post: [TimeSlider Plugin and Leaflet - Markers not appearing in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878087/timeslider-plugin-and-leaflet-markers-not-appearing-in-order))

But in fact, you should rather `sort` the `options.markers` array once you have created the `sliderControl`, because the order in the GeoJSON can potentially not be followed once it is read by the slider control.

So you would do something like:

```js
var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({layer:markers , range:true});

sliderControl.options.markers.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.properties.time > b.properties.time);
});

map.addControl(sliderControl);

sliderControl.startSlider();
```

**Note:** I updated the [first mentioned post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886588/how-to-use-leaflet-slider-along-with-markercluster-in-javascript) with a new method to make LeafletSlider compatible with Leaflet.markercluster. There is no longer need to modify LeafletSlider code, you just use an extra plugin called [Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport) (I am the author).

Comment: Also updated my [answer to the related post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35881206/5403120) to include the correct sorting method. Hopefully this will help avoid further confusion.

Comment: Thanks very much but sliderControl.options.markers.sort(...) does not work for me. It crashes the application with this error :

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of null"

Maybe that's because markers is not a layer but a cluster group ?

Comment: Ok now that I use your plugin Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport, I don't need to sort anymore. This is working.

I'm now facing another issue with your plugin. I want to combine the slider and the L.control.layer (ie, your 2 demos combined) with Cluster suport. But this is another topic.

Many thanks to you